# Is it possible to give items to other characters in Lego Lord of the Rings?

Tags: lego-lord-of-the-rings

In the "Cirith Ungol" level, you need to disguise both Frodo and Sam to enter the gate.  I accidentally used Frodo to pick up both masks, and can't seem to hand the second to Sam.

Is it possible to pass items between characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that particular situation your only option is to retry the level and be careful the next time, unfortunately. This is a glitch in the game. You don't say what platform you're on but on 360 you can drop items with the red button most of the time, however not these disguises for some reason.